# Column name duplicated when use Join operation leading to wrong parsing

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am working on a Golang project using `Gorm` for database manipulations.

When I perform a `Join()` operator on two tables that have two columns with the same name (`id`), it runs without any error or warning but there's a problem in parsing step with `Find()`, it reads `struct1.id` as `struct2.id`.

In following code, Im trying to fill the two arrays of two structs by joining two tables on some conditions.

```
var array1 []Struct1
var array2 []Struct2

queryRes := gormClient.Model(&Struct1{}).Select("*").
            Joins("Join table 2 on some conditions").
            Where("Other conditions").
            Find(&array1).Find(&array2)
```

I know that renaming the column names or struct tags of the models will help. But I wonder if there is any other solution being more convenient than modifying database structs. Thank you and appreciate your helps.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/5142)?

Comment: @kostix, thank you. I am using Gorm latest version from `gorm.io/gorm` package but the issue is remaining the same :(

Comment: Why not ask in the issue tracker then? Also "the latest version" is a moot term: if the changes mentioned in that issue (and the linked issue) are not yet a part of any official released version, and you're using the latest released version (and not the bleeding edge—i.e. the tip of the upstream's `master` branch) then it's quite possible your copy does not indeed contain this change yet.

Comment: I am using `Gorm 2.0` (git tag `v1.23.8`). In the issue tracker, the contributor scans joined tables to a new struct, usually a struct with two embedded structs. I didn't see he separately scan one by one like the way I do in the above code. I solve my problem by his way, thank you very much, @kostix !

Comment: If this works for you, you can post an answer describing the solution and accept it: that's perfectly fine on SO.

Comment: @kostix i did it.

Comment: Mark it as accepted as well ;-) This raises the rank of the question in the search output: because it has a working solution.

Comment: @kostix Thank you for reminding me but I can only accept the answer tomorrow :D (may be a new rule of SO)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been raised in this [thread](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/5142). The contributor solved this by creating a new struct containing two embedded structs, something likes following:

```
type Struct1And2 struct {
   Struct1   Struct1   `gorm:"embedded"`
   Struct2   Struct2   `gorm:"embedded"`
}
```

Then perform a query.

```
var struct1and2 []Struct1And2
var array1 []Struct1
var array2 []Struct2

gormClient.Model(&Struct1{}).Select("*").
        Joins("Join table 2 on some conditions").
        Where("Other conditions").
        Find(&struct1and2)
// Now we need one more step to build array1 and array2 from struct1and2 separately.
```

Anyway, I still hope `Gorm` support scanning structs one by one in future (like the way i did in my question), it looks convenient.